how to configure ARR reverse proxy and URL Rewrite for iis docker container?
I've run the iis docker container in my local windows server on port 250 and the container ip is (192.168.10.1) . I've point the local server public ip (31.56.#.#) to this domain name "testvault.info". and i host web site inside my above mentioned iis docker container. now need to point the above mentioned domain name to web site inside the docker iis container so how to configure arr reverse proxy for this scenario and point domain name to  web site inside  docker container
